# Send joined strings to function and return only Result::Error

Tags: rust

I have a struct with some functions and when something goes wrong I call a function `fn set_error(&self,msg:&str)` to log the error and possible show an error message etc.

Currently this is very simple and I use it like following in other functions:

```
pub fn somefunction(&self) {
  ...some code...
  if error == true {
    self.set_error("The error message");
    Err("The error message")
  }else{
    Ok("All ok")
  }
}
```

To begin with it could be useful for the `set_error()`-function to return a Result::Error object in some way so calling `set_error()` would be the same as:

```
  self.set_error("The error message");
  Err("The error message")
```

Another way could be to return the error-string again from the `set_error()`-function to be able to do:

```
  Err( self.set_error("The error message") )
```

Also, is there a simple/nice way to join/concat strings (String, &str etc) that is sent to the `set_error()`-function? For example, in match-Err there could be a std::io::error and maybe  a u32 where I would like to do:

```
  self.set_error("A lvl 10 Error occured: " +  err.to_string() + ". UserId:" + user_id.to_string() + ". Some other info...");
```

This thought is taken from PHP where that can be done to create the error string in the call to the function in a simple way.

How would a `set_error()`-function look to handle error in my scenario and how would I build an error-message, sent to `set_error()`, in a good way?

---

### More info:

Doing `self.set_error(format!("..Error..: {err}. UserId:{user_id}."))`, as suggested by user4815162342, results in problems when trying to do: `return Err( self.set_error(format!("..Error..: {err}. UserId:{user_id}.")) );`.
This is since Err() need a &str and if I change `self.set_error` to return &str then that &str only lives in the function and can't be used outside it.
If trying to do

```
fn set_error(&self,msg:String) -> String {
  println!("Err: {msg}");
  msg
}
...
return Err(self.set_error(format!("..Error..: {err}. UserId:{user_id}.").as_str());
...
```

Then I get:

```
cannot return value referencing temporary value.
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function.
```

So how would the `set_error()`-function look to be able to do:
`return Err(self.set_error(format!("..Error..: {err}. UserId:{user_id}."));` or similar?
I'm not looking to get exactly this to work but to get something easy to use to work.

Comment: I guess `set_error()` would receive a `msg: impl Into<String>`. That way you can call it with a string literal, as before, but also with a dynamically generated string, which you create with the usual `format!()`, e.g.: `self.set_error(format!("A lvl 10 Error occurred: {err}. UserId:{user_id}. Some other info..."))`. Convenience level comparable to PHP.

Comment: Can you explain where exactly you're stuck? All of your possibilities seem relatively straight forward to implement with the tip from user4815162342.

Comment: @cafce25 See my edited post about where I'm stuck.

Comment: If you might have to dynamically create the error it should be a `String`, not a `&str`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the format macro to concatenate the error strings.

```
format!("{}\n{}", previous_error, new_error);
```

Or vice versa

Comment: That will fail to borrow-check with the OP's definition of `set_error()`, which accepts a `&str`.